# Windows 7 Identifying... loop after update

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

After doing a Windows 7 update yesterday on my laptop. The wireless internet now just says  that it is:

```
Identifying... (router name)
No Internet Access
```

The network never seems to identify. What could have happened during the update that has caused this? Is there a way for me to undo the updates? I have a tried a System Restore, but the restore seems to fail every time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: I'm having the same issue even when hard-wired into the router. All other devices are connected just fine.

Comment: Can you ping your router from the command line? ping [router ip address]

Comment: I get transmit failed. General failure.

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried the usual resetting of the router? Do any other devices have this issue?

Comment: No other devices are having this issue and I reset the router in attempt to fix and no luck. The other devices are working just fine including the computer I'm currently typing this on. I tried hard-wiring the laptop into the router and I got the same error where it was trying to identify even while hard-wired.

Comment: You could try disabling/enable the laptops network adapter. Have you tried ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew? It may not work seeing that your laptop isn't communicating with the router.

Comment: I have tried release/renew and enable/disable of the network adapter. No luck, even tried a reinstall of the drivers. I got a 'No operation can be performed on the release/renew'.

Comment: What message do you receive when the System restore fails?

Comment: I just now noticed that if I disable my antivirus my System Restore is successful. However upon restore I'm still having the same connection issues.

Comment: Yeah, Antivrus software is usually the main culprit.

Comment: I just did a Troubleshoot and I have this issue: "Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings". I'm not sure if this helpful in resolving the issue or not.

Comment: Why don't you disable your antivirus software and do a System restore to a point before the update?

Comment: I did just that and I'm still having issues.

Comment: I've posted a possible solution/check you could do below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attempted System Restore, virus/malware scanning, router reset, proxy checks, winsock and ipv4 resets, ipconfig /release and /renew, reinstalling drivers, and updating drivers. With no resolution I ended up resetting to factory default which fixed everything.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution (Credit to GTS-NJ on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-could-not-automatically-detect-this/d243dea1-d1c8-4c4a-ba96-2b49bc9bab1a)):

> (This post is intended for all reporting the problem)
>
> Check Internet Options (from Control Panel or Internet Explorer Tools
>   / Options  /Connections Tab / LAN Settings and make sure Proxy Server
>   is unchecked even if using Firefox.  Check settings in Firefox in
>   Tools / Options /Advanced Connections / Settings  (should be either
>   use system proxy settings or no proxy).
>
> Check for malware especially using malwarebytes.
>
> Try  these two commands in that order in an elevated command prompt. 
>   Do the first one first then reboot and try.  If still bad try the
>   second.
>
> 1. netsh winsock reset
> 2. netsh int ipv4 reset
>
> If these don't help, please post the output of an ipconfig /all
>   command

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I will give this a shot and see what happens.